# Is there a way to search in current folder in file open dialogs?

Tags: finder, high-sierra, search

In normal finder window, I have set it to search in `current` folder by default.

However, when I want to open a file in the `open file` dialog, the search is still a global `Mac` search.

Is there anyway to limit it to search in the current folder like in normal finder?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by global search when you are talking about the open file dialog.  Open file should start out in your home folder or last folder you accessed with the app.

Comment: @jmh well the question is regarding the search box *in* the open file dialog. I have the same issue and setting search to `current folder` in the finder options does not help.